# dynamic string C# .ToTable(true, "Dynamic String Here");

Tags: c#, dynamic, defaultview

I am building a table on the fly in C#.  This table may or may not contain certain columns.  I need a row made up of the distinct values from a raw table.  (i.e. Agent Name, Manager Name etc).

I use:

```
var DistinctTable = SourceTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "AName", "MName");
```

and it works fine, but I need this to work with something like

```
    string Groupby = "";

    if (AName != "")
    {
        Groupby = AName;
    }
    if (MName != "")
    {
        Groupby = Groupby + MName;
    }

var DistinctTable = SourceTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, Groupby);
```

I'm dumbing this down a bit for simplicity but the premise is there.  I have tried options of adding in quotes, adding in comma's etc.  Nothing works the best I have done is to receive the error

There is no column '"AName","MName"' in table (x)

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As DistinctTable is being made (back?) into a DataTable you can therefore do this:

```
if (DistinctTable.Columns.Contains("ColumnName"))
{
    //[logic]
}
```

Edited to add:

```
DataTable DistinctTable = SourceTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
if (DistinctTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    if (!DistinctTable.Columns.Contains("ColumnA"))
    {
        DistinctTable.Columns.Add("ColumnA", typeof(String));
    }
    if (!DistinctTable.Columns.Contains("ColumnB"))
    {
        DistinctTable.Columns.Add("ColumnA", typeof(String));
    }
    if (!DistinctTable.Columns.Contains("ColumnC"))
    {
        DistinctTable.Columns.Add("ColumnC", typeof(String));
        //you can also move the new columns by using SetOrdinal, like so:
        DistinctTable.Columns[DistinctTable.Columns.Count - 1].SetOrdinal(DistinctTable.Columns.Count - 2);
        //but careful, this gets messy very quickly
    }
}
//return DistinctTable //(?)
```

Comment: I potentially need multiple columns to be distinct.  How can I start making (back) into a DataTable if I haven't finished the request?

Comment: `ToTable()` converts your `DataView` to a `DataTable`.  You can always add columns into the DataTable by doing `DistinctTable.Columns.Add("AName", typeof(String));` You can use that in conjunction with `Contains` to ensure you only add the column when necessary.

Comment: Updated answer for a better example/clarification

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `DefaultView.ToTable` is `params string[]` so you should be able to create an array to pass into it.

```
List<string> groupBys = new List<string>();

if (AName != "")
{
    groupBys.Add(AName);
}
if (MName != "")
{
    groupBys.Add(MName);
}

var DistinctTable = SourceTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, groupBys.ToArray());
```

Comment: A great Idea and I attempted this but I get the same error about the column  not being in the table.

Comment: My Mistake.  Thank you VERY Much Juharr.  This worked!! I was working on this very late last night and I truly thought I had tried a string.